# How do you measure responsiveness and load time for WinForms

Tags: winforms

There is need to add to the .net windows application measurement of the responsiveness and load time for the windows forms.

What is correct way to measure winform response and load time?

Comment: The System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class offers good functionality for this purpose.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It is true, but in your answer there is not answer on question: what events do I need to track in order to measure response time for the windows app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would measure responsiveness but for load time you can log the [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) elapssed milliseconds of the successive events that are raised when a Form loads. Based on [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN we learn the events raised (in order) are:

- Control.HandleCreated
- Control.BindingContextChanged
- Form.Load
- Control.VisibleChanged
- Form.Activated
- Form.Shown

You can hookup these events in the constructor of a form and have a simple `Log` method to handle the data collection. Be aware that collecting the data also takes time.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Stopwatch timing = new Stopwatch();

    // naive data collection
    void Log(string stage)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", timing.ElapsedMilliseconds, stage));
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        timing.Start();
        Log("Constructor Start");
        InitializeComponent();  // adding all designer generated stuff
        Log("Constructor - Initialized");
        // hookup events
        this.HandleCreated += (s, e) => Log("HandleCreated");
        this.BindingContextChanged += (s,e)=> Log("BindingContextChanged");
        this.Load += (s, e) => Log("Load");
        this.Activated += (s, e) => Log("Activated");
        this.Shown += (s, e) => Log("Shown"); ;
        Log("Constructor End");
    }
}
```

On my laptop with .Net 4.0 in Debug the timings are as follows:

> 0 = Constructor Start
>        19 = Constructor - Initialized
>        20 = Constructor End
>        22 = HandleCreated
>        24 = BindingContextChanged
>        25 = Load
>        30 = Activated
>        31 = Shown